# Eclipse claiming error when calling method from external class

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, static, call

For some reason, I noticed today when I tried to make a static method, eclipse did not let me call it in a different class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void test(){

    }
}
```

Other class:

```
public class Proof {
    Main.test();
}
```

And for Main.test() it says: "Syntax error on token "test", Identifier expected after this 
 token"
If anyone knows the issue, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the method out naked in the class, not in a method, constructor or other block, and this is not proper Java syntax and is not allowed. Solution, call it in a method, such as a main method.

So change

```
public class Proof {
    Main.test();  // you can't call this here
}
```

to

```
public class Proof {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.test();  // but here it should work just fine!
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow duh. I was just testing out the new version of eclipse and thought this was a bug. Thanks. I can get back to my program now with the new eclipse :D

Comment: @TheFancyWhale: but it **is** a bug! But it's a bug in **your** code! :) There's a good lesson to learn here, one I've learned many times: whenever I think about blaming Java or Eclipse about a bug, first look for the bug in my own code, because the odds of it being me vs. them as the source of the bug is about 10000000 to 1, or even greater. It's likely the same for you.